# How to use old commits in git?

Tags: java, git

I'm making java project using git and JavaGit library. I need to execute some actions with the files from previous commits. I specify the path to the repository. How can I get the path to previous commits?

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws JavaGitException, IOException {
    File repositoryDirectory = new File("\\Library\\build\\jar\\");

    FindBugs fb = new FindBugs(repositoryDirectory);
    fb.findBugs();

    for (Commit c : fb.getDotGit().getLog()) {
        //here i need to execute findBugs() method to every commit
        //how could I do this?
        System.out.println(c.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: Git does not work like that.  You need to checkout a given commit in order to let FindBugs access the files for that commit.

Comment: Thx. So how could I checkout every commit and then restore the last one?

Comment: As you are still a bit unexperienced with git, you might be using a wrong approach for whatever end result you need to achieve.  The simplest way to get findbugs statistics up and running may simply be to have Jenkins watch your repository and run findbugs when it changes.  If it is something else, please elaborate.  Additionally git scripting is typically much easier under Linux.